# How to get the first name and display it instead of the email in the Angular Template of ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I created a new solution in Visual Studio 2022 using the template "ASP.NET Core with Angular", .NET 7, and Individual Authentication. When I run the application and test it by registering a new user after extending the IdentityUser with a new class based on that to add First Name and Last Name:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I log in, the app shows the email instead of the First Name and Last Name.
[image]

This app is configured to get the user as follows from the front end in the authorize.service.ts:

```
  public async completeSignIn(url: string): Promise<IAuthenticationResult> {
    try {
      await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();
      const user = await this.userManager!.signinCallback(url);
      this.userSubject.next(user && user.profile);
      return this.success(user && user.state);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('There was an error signing in: ', error);
      return this.error('There was an error signing in.');
    }
  }
```

In the component login-menu the username is gotten as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.authorizeService.isAuthenticated();
    this.userName = this.authorizeService.getUser().pipe(map(u => u && u.name));
  }
```

My question is: How can I get the FirstName and LastName in the client app? And then in the login-menu.html show that instead of the email.

Comment: search with Hello in the solution and check what you have to change. probably needed to add new field in IUser interface

Comment: Even if I added it, that property comes as null. It has to be sent somewhere in the backend.

Comment: I'm afraid it's first to add first name & last name column in the database, as the default identity model, there's no such column in the user table.

Comment: Yes. I added those fields to the database. After some research on Microsoft learning and reading the documentation of Duende IdentityServer I found a solution using IProfileService. I will update the question with the answer.